# Natbib is citing articles with the "et al" construction and the full name

Tags: natbib

I'm using Overleaf, Natbib, with [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/science-journal) template.

I'm new to Bibtex, Natbib and the likes. I still can't find an answer to my problem on the forum or anywhere else, yet I believe it is very simple.

The issue is, when cited and at the references page, the articles are being referred to as "Author 1 et al. Author 1, author 2 and author 3"

I'd like to get rid of the "et al" construction.

I'm citing using `\cite{}` and `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}`

As an example of what is happening:

```
@article{doz2012quasi,
  title={A quasi--maximum likelihood approach for large, approximate dynamic factor models},
  author={Doz, Catherine and Giannone, Domenico and Reichlin, Lucrezia},
  journal={Review of economics and statistics},
  volume={94},
  number={4},
  pages={1014--1024},
  year={2012},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}
```

Is turning into in-text:

```
(Doz et al.(2012)Doz,Giannone, and Reichlin)
```

And the reference:

```
Doz et al.(2012)Doz, Giannone, and Reichlin. C.Doz,D.Giannone,andL.Reichlin. Aquasi– maximum likelihood approach for large, approximate dynamic factor models. Review of economics and statistics, 94(4):1014–1024, 2012.
```

Also, if possible, I'd like to get rid of the parenthesis on the in-text citation.

I've tried changing the bibliography styles to:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliographystyle{rusnat}
\bibliographystyle{ksfh_nat}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}
```

but none of them worked. Surely, I've tried them one at a time, the code block above is just a list.

I could not load the Natbib package, since whenever I tried overleaf it does not compile (it says that  `Command \NAT@parse already defined`). But from what I understand, the template already loads it. Perhaps inside one of the following packages:

```
\usepackage{scicite}
\usepackage{times}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should only use one bibliographystyle and load the natbib package correctly.  Please post a minimal document showing what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've used only one at a time, but I tried all of those. I incremented a little bit about the package loading. Hope it suffices

Comment: god.. just realized the scicite perhaps is another citing package, if there is such a thing.

Comment: scicite is a variant of cite which generally doesn't play well with natbib. You can probably drop it in favour of natbib without much issue.